# Open .indd file in iphone application using objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5, adobe-indesign

I need to open magazines in my iphone application. But magazines have extension .indd.
I found a lot but i can't get any clue or example how to do this.

So my question is

- How to open .indd file using objective-c in iphone and if possible please provide me a link or demo example .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) What problems are you having?

Comment: You can save the `.indd` file as a `.pdf` file using InDesign.

Answer (score 1):

With my knowledge a .indd file is a binary file. So you can do absolutely nothing with it on iOS. What you need is [Indesign Server](http://www.adobe.com/nl/products/indesignserver.html) to parse / read those files.